# UNIX export command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to understand the use of `export` command.

I tried using `man export`, but there is no manual for this command.

Can anyone please help me out understanding the use of `export` in UNIX?

Comment: its extremely weird that there isn't a man page for it. I don't see one either.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

When you execute a program the child program inherits its environment variables from the parent. For instance if `$HOME` is set to `/root` in the parent then the child's `$HOME` variable is also set to `/root`.

This only applies to environment variable that are marked for export. If you set a variable at the command-line like

```
$ FOO="bar"
```

That variable will not be visible in child processes. Not unless you export it:

```
$ export FOO
```

You can combine these two statements into a single one in bash (but not in old-school sh):

```
$ export FOO="bar"
```

Here's a quick example showing the difference between exported and non-exported variables. To understand what's happening know that `sh -c` creates a child shell process which inherits the parent shell's environment.

```
$ FOO=bar
$ sh -c 'echo $FOO'

$ export FOO
$ sh -c 'echo $FOO'
bar
```

**Note:** To get help on shell built-in commands use `help export`. Shell built-ins are commands that are part of your shell rather than independent executables like `/bin/ls`.

Answer (score 17):

Unix

The commands env, set, and printenv display all environment variables and their values. env and set are also used to set environment variables and are often incorporated directly into the shell. printenv can also be used to print a single variable by giving that variable name as the sole argument to the command.

In Unix, the following commands can also be used, but are often dependent on a certain shell.

```
export VARIABLE=value  # for Bourne, bash, and related shells
setenv VARIABLE value  # for csh and related shells
```

You can have a look at [this](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_export.htm) at

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that the classic Bourne shell would require: `VARIABLE=value; export VARIABLE` rather than assign and export at once. The `set` command in C Shell is for shell variables rather than environment variables; `setenv` is the counterpart of `export`. The `set` command in Bourne-derived shells prints all variables, not just exported (environment) variables. Historically at least, the `env` command is separate from the shell (not a built-in), though it could easily be made into a built-in. It sets the environment for a specific command, not the shell that runs it.

Answer (score 5):

`export` is a built-in command of the [`bash` shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) and other [Bourne shell variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).   It is used to mark a shell variable for export to child processes.

Answer (score 0):

`export` is used to set environment variables. For example:

```
export EDITOR=pico
```

Will set your default text editor to be the `pico` command.