# Preserve environments vars after shell script finishes

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, environment-variables

How can I keep the environment variables, set from a shell script, after the script finishes running?

Comment: Use the export command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328223/unix-export-command

Comment: Add them to the file `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @CongXu `export` passes variables down to the child, not up to the parent.

Comment: Why are you asking? Why do you want to keep those environment variables? Do you really care about keeping all of them? Why does keeping e.g. `WINDOWID` or `SSH_AGENT_PID` is important to you?

Comment: You could also make your script a bash `function` defined in your `$HOME/.bashrc`

Answer (score 24):

This is not possible by *running* the script. The script spawns it's own sub-shell which is lost when the script completes.

In order to preserve `export`s that you may have in your script, call it

- either as

  ```sh
  . myScript.sh
  ```
- or

  ```sh
  source myScript.sh
  ```

Notice the space between the `.` and `myScript.sh`; also note that "[`source` is a synonym for `.` in Bash, but not in POSIX `sh`, so for maximum compatibility use the period.](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html#:%7E:text=source%20is%20a%20synonym%20for%20dot%2Fperiod%20%27.)"

Comment: What is the difference between "." and "./ "?

Answer (score 11):

run the script as follows:

```
source <script>

-OR-

. <script>
```

This will run the script in the current shell, and define variables in the current shell. The variables will then be retained in the current shell after the script is done.

Comment: What is the difference between "." and "./ "?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables exist the the environment that is private to each process.  The shell passes a COPY of exported variables to it's children as their environment, but there is no way for them to pass their environment back to the parent or any process other than their children.
You can print those variables and load them into the parent.
Or as has been already mentioned, you can run your script in the current shell with either "source script" or ". script" (and you might need ./script if . isn't in your PATH).
Some tools print their vars and the shell can load them using backticks like `ssh-agent`.  That way whatever ssh-agent prints will be run as a command.  If it prints something like  "VAR1=VAL;VAR2=VAL2" that may do what you want.