# Multilayer Web Application Deployment and Access

Tags: apache, web-services, tomcat8

I hava a situation.
I have one  **.war file say  APP-1** which expose **SOAP service**  for ex. getAccountTxn and I have another  **.war file say  APP-2** which consume this web service. 
Now I want to create one more  **.war file say  APP-3** which expose **REST webservice** which can be consumed by any client. I want to deploy APP-2 & APP-3 on the same server (i.e. Apache Tomcat).
Now the question is 
*"How can I access getAcccountTxn from APP-3 and consider APP-2 doesn't expose any web API?"* or 
*"How to call APP-2 from APP-3 without any web API?".*

Replies are Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set CATALINA_BASE to the appropriate directory, before launching the second instance:

export CATALINA_BASE=/path/to/tomcatInstance2

**Update**

"[export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328223/unix-export-command)" is a unix command. On Windows you need to call "[set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)". Change you batch files like this:

```
@echo off
set CATALINA_BASE="D:/RiverMA/javadevenviroment/Stage1/apache-tomca/tomcat-instance1"
pushd %CATALINA_BASE%\bin
call startup.bat
exit
```

Comment: "it didn't work for me !!" ... thats bad, what did you do wrong?

Comment: I created two startup.bat file and made change in startup-instance1.bat "export CATALINA_BASE=D:/RiverMA/javadevenviroment/Stage1/apache-tomcat/tomcat-instance1
cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
./startup.bat" and similarly in startup-instance2.bat, and it didn't work